# Error: Truncated incorrect double value

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have created a trigger like this:

```
create trigger mydb.t_count  after insert
on mydb.titles 
for each row 
update  mydb.authors set titles_count= 'titles_count'+1 where author_id=new.author_id;
```

While inserting a row in titles tables I am getting error stating

> Truncated incorrect double value:titles_count

I think something has to be changed in update command. How to perform arithmetic operations in it? I need to increment the `titles_count` value (author table) by 1 whenever a row is inserted in titles table...

Comment: `update  mydb.authors set titles_count= titles_count+1` There is no need for `'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Comment: Even when I remove the single quotes I am getting the same error ...Truncated incorrect double value:titles_count..while inserting a record in titles table.Thank you for helping